# where are variables such as SYMROOT or DSTROOT defined in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, variables, build

I'd like to change DSTROOT(or any other variables that Xcode use for build settings)  to somewhere else but can't to locate where it's defined.

I'm using Xcode 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [Xcode Build Settings Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html), it looks like `$DSTROOT` is only affected by `$PROJECT_NAME` and `$SYMROOT` is only affected by `$SRCROOT`, so I'm not sure you can easily change them at all.

Comment: where can I change project_name or srcroot?

Comment: @Eugene You'd have to rename the project and move the source; not practical.  What is using `$DSTROOT` and `$SYMROOT` that you want to change?